# Galaxy 6 phone to use as USB to download ISO?

Tags: boot, usb, bios

Have an old laptop that stopped working using fedora one day and now won't boot. The CD/ROM drive on the laptop is also broken...only thing I can do is via USB stick maybe...but now can't download the iso using the laptop..so can I maybe download Ubuntu to a memory stick from my Galaxy S6 smartphone and boot the laptop up using that?  I know of an app that would take care of all that but which requires root and I'm on contract with the phone so can't get it rooted. Any way out of this?